# Are there any consequences of changing utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci in MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql, version

There are a bunch of Wordpress websites on my cPanel server that I wish to move to Plesk. Source server has MySQL 5.1 on it and destination has 5.5

An error that I saw while migrating is that the utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  data type isn't compatible with the destination MysQL version 5.5.

If I were to make a change on the cPanel server with the type from utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  to utf8mb4_unicode_ci - will that affect anything on it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. MySQL's implementation of utf8mb4 began with 5.5.3. That said, if I was migrating, I really wouldn't bother with anything prior to 8.0 (or the MariaDB equivalent)

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry. Basically my live server has mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.30-MariaDB and destination server has Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB. 
The destination mysql says utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci is an unknown collation. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. It's MariaDB, not MySQL, so that's fine. But I can't help further; this question might be better directed to the dba forum

Comment: Mariadb 10.2 has a lot of cool sql features that aren't in 5.5.  why take such a big jump backwards?  Don't assume it is going to be anything close to painless.

Comment: @Strawberry and ysth - I read Plesk's documentation about how to upgrade the MariaDB services and did that, and it worked out quite well. Thanks for your help.